# save cv_results_['params'] from grid search as csv

Tags: python, csv, grid-search

I would like to save my scores and parameters used in my grid search as a csv file. The problem is, that the parameters are all saved in the same column. Here is an example:

```
param_grid=dict(batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs)

grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=-1, cv=3)
grid_result = grid.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), callbacks=[es])

means = grid_result.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
stds = grid_result.cv_results_['std_test_score']
param = grid_result.cv_results_['params']

exportfile='/Users/test.csv'
with open(exportfile, 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    for mean, stdev, param in zip(means, stds, params):
        writer.writerow([mean, stdev, param])
```

The output of the param is like this:

{'batch_size': 40, 'epochs': 1000}

but I want to reduce it to:

40, 1000

Answer (score 0):

If `params = {'batch_size': 40, 'epochs': 1000}`
then do

`list(params.values())` and this will be `[40, 1000]`.

If `params` is an array of hashes, i.e: `[{'batch_size': 40, 'epochs': 1000}, {'batch_size': 30, 'epochs': 1100}]` then you can do this:

`list(map(lambda p: list(p.values()), params))` this will result in: `[[40, 1000], [30, 1100]]`

Comment: Hi, your first line of code seems promising. But when add my colde like this:

    for mean, stdev, param in zip(means, stds, params):
            writer.writerow([mean, stdev, list(param.values())])

The result in my CSV file looks like this:

"[30, 0.0, 0.0, 1000, 0.001, 400, 700, 600]"

Answer (score 0):

You can change it to pandas dataframe first and then change it to csv:

```
 import pandas as pd

 df = pd.DataFrame(grid_result.cv_results_)
 df.to_csv('result.csv')
```